# NavigationController configurado como transparente se carga con color de la vista anterior

Tags: swift, scroll, navigation

Tengo una vista configurada con el NavigationController como transparente, sin embargo cuando la vista se carga, el color inicial del NavBar se carga con el color del NavBar de la vista que le precede.

En mi vista 1 (anterior), tengo configurado mi NavBar de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor =  UIColor.red // uicolorFromHex(0x20AB7E)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    let navigationBackgroundView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first
    navigationBackgroundView?.alpha = 1.0

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)]

}
```

Puede que el codigo tenga lineas de mas, lineas de menos, pero funciona.
 y en mi vista afectada tengo:

```
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 0 ) { //(bounds.height/2)
        let rest = self.tableView.contentOffset.y / (self.tableView.frame.size.height - bounds.height/2)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent//Default
        let navigationBackgroundView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.first
        navigationBackgroundView?.alpha = rest //0.8
        tituloImagenEtiqueta.textColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1-rest)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(rest)]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x20AB7E).withAlphaComponent(rest)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        titulo.title = currentObject
    } else {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0)]

    }


}
```

Lo anterior, me va aumentando el alpha del NavBar a medida que me desplazo hacia abajo de tal manera que llega a ser totalmente visible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al igual que el anterior fragmento, funciona. Sin embargo, cuando la vista afectada carga, el color del NavBar carga en rojo, y al mas minimo scroll el color rojo desaparece y ahora si el NavBar se vuelve transparente y hace lo que esta en el metodo scrollViewDidScroll

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en mi vista afectada agrego el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage! = UIImage()
    self.navigationController!.isToolbarHidden = false
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Al cargar la vista afectada, esta me carga, en transparente, sin embargo lo que hay en el metodo scrollViewDidScroll no funciona. Al dar scroll el alpha del NavBar no se aplica por lo que siempre sigue siendo transparente.

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner la parte en la que se hace transparente en el método viewDidLoad?

Comment: He intentado ponerlo en casi todos los metodos. ViewDidApper, ViewWillAppear, ViewWillLayoutSubview, ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear. Pero el color de la vista 1 se arrastra al de la 2.

Comment: Me imagino que lo solucionaste colocando el codigo dento de override func **viewDidDisappear**(_ animated: Bool) {} ? Saludos